# Running a project if has been downloaded from the internet causes errors

Tags: c#

I copied this project from another computer where it worked correctly, but in this I get these errors.

I have already recompiled the project, can someone help me with the solution?

Error:

> The ReportesExport \ sales4.resx file can not be processed because it
>   is on the Internet or in a restricted area, or it has the Web mark.
>   Remove this mark if you want to process the files

[image]

Comment: Please post English text, not pictures.

Comment: Images of your entire desktop are not helpful. Please post the text you've outlined, translated to English (this is an English language site), and in plain text.

Comment: For spanish error messages as on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was likely downloaded, you need to unblock each of your source files

1. Right-click on the file and select Properties from the menu.
2. Click Unblock on the General tab.
3. Click OK.
4. Repeat for all files needed

[image]